# How to properly assign value to model column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my console I have one thing that is working and I need to make a method for it.

```
@sale.weight = @sale.fisherman.fish.sum(:weight)
```

Here I assign right part to the column **weight** on model **Sale**.

The question is how to write a method for this?

The following approach didn't work out for me. In this case the column remains nil after calculation.

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  def calculate_total_weight
    weight = fisherman.fish.sum(:weight)
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? Any error ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, need to use `self`, otherwise `weight` will be treated as local variable. Like :

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  def calculate_total_weight
    self.weight = fisherman.fish.sum(:weight)
  end
end
```

Follow [Why does attr_accessor in module require 'self.'?](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/185481) to know the reason of using `self` explicitly.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!